Getting rid of empty responses
I have sets of responses to a survey on various dates and I want to set up a visualization of each person's responses over time. I figured out facets which is super cool and definitely what I'm wanting but it's not quite right and has some extra space that makes it kind of confusing.
I ended up with this
ggplot(data = df_name) +
  +   geom_point(mapping = aes(x=Response,y=Statement,color=Date)) +
  +   facet_grid(~Name)

and got mostly what I wanted with this
Photo of the vis I have right now
But I don't want to have all of these empty dates for each person I only want their responses over time.
I've tried a few suggested ways of getting rid of these like filtering out those responses, and na.rm
But nothing is working and I'm getting more and more confused.

Try with facet_grid(~cyl, scales = "free_x") to get rid of the unused categories on the scale. Additionally try ´facet_grid(~cyl, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") to  set the width of the facet panels according to the number of categories.
